# output of print statement is not clear

Tags: java, for-loop

```
int i, tem = 3;
i = tem;
for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
    for (int j = 1; j< tem; j++) {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}
```

The above code prints `a` 8 times. I'm not able to understand why.

Comment: It doesn't print a 8 times. It prints it 4*3 times.

Comment: a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  this is the output i am getting...

Comment: @ABAJAVa no way https://ideone.com/61Id4d

Comment: Now that you changed the condition of the inner loop, it prints a 4*2 times.

Comment: Take a paper and pen and trace it out. Check the conditions of your loops and see why "a" is printed 8 times.

Comment: Yes inner loop is j<temp, it came like j<=temp..   I did not able to trace it out so came here.  Just tell me print statment is for inner loop or for both inner and outer loop. My understanding is only for inner loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int j = 1; j < tem; j++)
```

The above code runs for `j=1` to `j=2`, that is **2** times and will print

```
a
a
```

Now the for loop

```
for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++)
```

will execute the above printing **4** times (`x = 0 to 3`). So overall your code will print **8** times.

```
a //x=0
a
a //x=1
a
a //x=2
a
a //x=3
a
```

Comment: thanks so u mean to say once it enters the j for loop it will not go out until condition is FALSe.. means it will not increment x for loop until the value of j==3.. ? correct .. ?

Comment: I have one more doubt in the print statement if am printing value of j it is print like 1 2 1 2 eight times... why even after exiting the inner loop the it is printing 1 2 .. it must be only 2 the value of j

Comment: Once the inner for loop exits, the value of J is 2. That's correct. But now x increments it's value and the inner loop again starts from j=1. So here is how it happens, x=0 J=1,2 x=1 J=1,2 x=2 J=1,2 x=3 J=1,2

Comment: Thanks, So finally when ever the inner loops comes it will start from the initial value of the variable and executes the condition and statement.

Answer (score 0):

The first `for` iterates from 0 to 3, that's **4** times.

The second `for` iterates from 1 to 3, that's **3** times.

Since the first `for` is inside the second, the print will happen 3 times * 4, that's **12**.

If you need it to be 8 prints, you should change `<=` for an `<` either in the first or the second `for`.

Comment: More or else I got your point, but my understanding was after j loop first time it will print a like wise it must print only 3 times. when j<tem i .e 3<3 means it should not execute print statement . Print statement must execute only when inner loop is true.  Is my understand correct..??

Comment: 2nd for was j <=  tem.  Now that its corrected, it runs only 2 times (j as 1 and 2) , so its 2 times = 8. The x loop runs as 0, jumos to j loop, prints 2 times a, goes back to x, as 1, j loop prints 2 more a's, back to x=2, j loops two more times, back to x=3, j loops 2 more for a total 8 and ends

Answer (score 0):

It should not print 'a' for **8** times. The following program print 'a' for 4*3=**12** times.

```
 public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        int i, tem = 3;
        i = tem;

        for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= tem; j++) {
                System.out.println("a");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try executing the above program and you will get correct number of 'a' (12 times) instead of 8 a's.

Comment: hey it is not j<=tem, it is j<temp. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

consider iteration one x=0 and tem=3 so inner for loop iterates twice for conditions j=1 and j=2. Second iteration now x=1 and tem=3 in this case also inner loop iterates twice for j=1 and j=2 .This process continues for x=2 and x=3 as well ,so finally first for loop condition gets passed for 4 times i.e x=0,x=1,x=2 and x=3 and inner for loop condition passes twice for every first for loop condition getting passed so it prints 4*2 times which is eight times

Comment: so the when outer for loop is at firs iteration ,0<3  condition is true it goes to inner for loop there also condition is true 1<3  ..  Now first time it prints 'a'    second time outer for is at 1<=3 it enters the inner for loop and there 2<3 condition is true prints 'a' . So now 'a a' is printed  Now the outer for loop is at third iteration 2<=3 condition is true condition  goes to inner for loop 3<3 FALSE just prints 'a'   Again out for loop 3<=3 comes to inner for loop condition is FALSE just prints 'a' .Totally it must print 4 times a.  'a,a,a,a' is my understanding correct

Comment: from your comment above when 1<3 in inner loop it prints a for first time and then it wont skip to upper for loop iteration goes on in inner loop for 2<3 and it prints a for the second time and then once inner for loop is completely done it moves to first for loop

Comment: Thanks, I got it. so now how many for condition in one inner loop it will first try to reach the condition and then moves to next one. Once all inner loop condition is completed it will come out and increment the outer loop.   And again it enters the inner and check the condition. I am correct.. ??

Comment: I have one more doubt in the print statement if am printing value of j it is print like 1 2 1 2 eight times... why even after exiting the inner loop the it is printing 1 2 .. it must be only 2 the value of j

Answer (score 0):

Sometime is useful to use the debugger, and in cases like this where you are looping every now and then
    printin the indexs to see/proof the "logic"

your code is kind of a pitfall with the indexs in the for loops 
    but you can replace the printline and verify that

- the outter loop is from 0 to 3: 4 times
- the inner loop is from 1 to 2: 2 times

  ergo 4x2 times  printing the char a

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, tem = 3;
    i = tem;
    for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < tem; j++) {
            System.out.println("x: " + x + ",j:" + j);
        }
    }
}
```